# Update to JDK 17 and Gradle 7.4.2

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, java-17

I am using JDK 17 (temurin-17.jdk), so I need to use gradle version 7 > (I am using https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip);

When I try to build my project, I get the following error:

**

Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Task :bootJar FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':bootJar' (type 'BootJar').
In plugin 'org.springframework.boot' type 'org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.bundling.BootJar' property 'bootInf' is missing an input or output annotation.

Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.

Possible solutions:

Add an input or output annotation.
Mark it as @internal.
Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.

**

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    classpath("net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.1")
    classpath("com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.1.0")
    classpath("gradle.plugin.org.hidetake:gradle-swagger-generator-plugin:2.18.1")
  }
}

 //Technically any privileged credentials will work, but intended to be the service account
def service_username = System.getenv('SERVICE_USERNAME')
def service_password = System.getenv('SERVICE_PASSWORD')

def configDir = "$project.projectDir/config"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://ci1.mycwt.com/nexus/repository/Development_Artifacts/" }
    mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    jcenter()
}

group = 'com.somethingSomething'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
apply plugin: 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator'


bootRun {
    jvmArgs '-javaagent:AppServerAgent-1.8-20.8.0.30686/ver20.8.0.30686/javaagent.jar'
}

test{
  jvmArgs  '-javaagent:AppServerAgent-1.8-20.8.0.30686/ver20.8.0.30686/javaagent.jar'
}
/**
 * PMD Configurations
 */
pmd {
    toolVersion = '6.22.0'
    ruleSetFiles = files('config/cwtRuleSet.xml')
    ruleSets = []
    ignoreFailures = false
    pmdTest.enabled = false
}
tasks.withType(Pmd) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

/**
 * Jacoco Configurations
 */
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification{
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.93
            }
        }
        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, excludes: ['**/com/somethingSomething/config/**',
                                             '**/com/somethingSomething//nextgen/config/**',
                                             '**/com/somethingSomething/model/**',
                                             '**/com/somethingSomething/*Application*',
                                             '**/com/somethingSomething//nextgen/web/**',
                                             '**/com/somethingSomething/preferencing/service/Invalid*'])
            }))
        }
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, excludes: ['**/com/somethingSomething/config/**',
                                         '**/com/somethingSomething//nextgen/config/**',
                                         '**/com/somethingSomething/model/**',
                                         '**/com/somethingSomething/*Application*',
                                         '**/com/somethingSomething//nextgen/web/**',
                                         '**/com/somethingSomething/preferencing/service/Invalid*'])
        }))
    }
}

build.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
build.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
jacocoTestCoverageVerification.shouldRunAfter jacocoTestReport

/**
 * Checkstyle Configurations
 */
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = 8.30
    ignoreFailures = false
    maxErrors = 0
    maxWarnings = 5 //There are known issues with lambdas and line wraps not being evaluated correctly in checkstyle
    configFile = project(':').file("$configDir/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    configProperties = ['suppressionFile': project(':').file("$configDir/checkstyle/suppressions.xml")]
}

task generateJavaDocs(type: Javadoc) {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  failOnError = false
  title= "Service"
}

release {
  afterReleaseBuild.dependsOn publish
}

publish {
  dependsOn build
    repositories {
        maven {
            {
                url= nexusReleaseURL
                credentials {
                    username = service_username
                    password = service_password
                }
            }
            {
                url= nexusSnapshotURL
                credentials {
                    username = service_username
                    password = service_password
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bootJar {
  baseName = "${jarBaseName}"
  enabled = true
  //classifier = "${grgit.head().id}"
}

springBoot {
  mainClassName = "com.somethingSomething.ServiceApplication"
  buildInfo()
}

sourceCompatibility = 17
targetCompatibility = 17

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.1034'
    }
}

task bootRunWithLocalProfile {
    description 'This runs the application with the local profile activated, which uses local redis, logs to ' +
            'the console, and disables AppDynamics.'
    doFirst {
        bootRun.configure {
            systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'local'
        }
    }
    group 'application'

    finalizedBy bootRun
}

task bootRunWithMockDataSources {
    description 'This runs the application with the local and mockdata profiles activated, which uses local redis, ' +
            'logs to the console, disables AppDynamics, and replaces select external integrations with mock ' +
            'services from mock-services'
    doFirst {
        println 'Make sure you have the appropriate mock-services running, or the server ' +
                'won\'t function properly...'
        bootRun.configure {
            systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'local,mockdata'
        }
    }
    group 'application'

    finalizedBy bootRun
}

dependencies {
  implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-translate')

  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.1.RELEASE")
  implementation("com.somethingSomething:commons:1.0-SNAPSHOT")

//  implementation("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18")

  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json")
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

  implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis")
  implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.8")
  implementation("org.apache.sis.core:sis-referencing:0.7")
  implementation("com.cwt.eit.springboot.utils:load-balancer-control:1.0.8")
  implementation("org.jblas:jblas:1.2.4");

  compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
  annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20')
  implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4')
  implementation('io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core')
  implementation('com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:3.1.3')
  implementation('com.appdynamics.agent:agent-api:4.5.18.29239')
  implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.2")
  implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.6.0")
  implementation("org.json:json:20180813")
  implementation('com.cwt.dna:amenity-parser:2.3.16')

  implementation('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1')
  implementation('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1')
  implementation('org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:2.4.4')
  implementation('org.glassfish.metro:webservices-api:2.4.4')
  implementation('com.cwt.bpg.services.common:security-jwt:3.11.0'){
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.camel')
    exclude(group: 'org.springframework')
  }
  implementation('com.cwt.bpg.services.common:security-model:3.11.0'){
    exclude(group: 'org.apache.camel')
    exclude(group: 'org.springframework')
  }

  testImplementation("org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.7.4")

  testImplementation('junit:junit:4.12')
  testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:4.0.0')
  testImplementation('net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.11.21')
  testImplementation('com.appdynamics.agent:agent-api:4.5.18.29239')
  testImplementation('commons-io:commons-io:2.6')
  testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.1.RELEASE")

  testImplementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.16")

  swaggerUI 'org.webjars:swagger-ui:3.23.0'
}

swaggerSources {
  swagger {
    inputFile = file('swagger.yaml')
  }
}
```

Thank you for looking into this.

I expect the project to build and run successfully.

Comment: As the error message says, the problem is the "org.springframework.boot" plugin - the version 2.1.1 of that plugin is not compatible with Gradle 7 and later. Note that Spring Boot 2.1.1 is very old and has several serious security problems so you should upgrade Spring Boot to a more current version anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [upgrade guide from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html).  You have a lot of stuff that needs to change in your build.  For example, `compileOnly` is deprecated, as are some of your plugins.  This is all outlined in the linked guide, as well as the steps to fix it.

Comment: Where did you read that "compileOnly" is deprecated? "compile" and "runtime" have been removed with Gradle 7.0 (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#sec:configuration_removal), but the docs say nothing about "compileOnly" - even the documentation for Gradle 8 (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_dependency_management_overview) still uses "compileOnly" without anything about it being deprecated.